# How do I interpret the point estimates in the examples for the "survey" package?

Tags: r, survey

I'm using the `survey` package in R to estimate **point estimates and confidence intervals for proportions** calculated from a survey that uses replicate weights to account for a complex survey design. I'm working through the examples that come with the `survey` package in R and don't understand:

1. Why the "formula" argument for the `svyciprop` function, which needs a binary variable, works even when the variable is clearly not binary;
2. What the "formula" call `~I(emer==0` in the examples means; and
3. What the outputted values represent--ostensibly a proportion, but a proportion of *what*?

The examples come from p. 81 of the documentation for `survey` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf):

```
require(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, fpc=~fpc, data=apiclus1)
rclus1<-as.svrepdesign(dclus1)

svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="li")
svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="lo")
svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="as")
svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="be")
svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="me")
```

**Question 1**. The documentation says the the first argument for `svyciprop`, "formula", is a "[m]odel formula specifying a single binary variable." However, the "emer" variable (percentage of teachers with emergency credentials) in the above example is *not* a binary variable:

```
> summary(apiclus1$emer)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    3.00    8.00   10.74   16.00   49.00 
>
```

**Question 2**. What does the formula `~I(emer==0)` do or evaluate? Some quantity conditional on "emer" equaling 0? And why is the "I" necessary?

**Question 3**. How should I interpret the output?

```
> svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="be")
                      2.5% 97.5%
I(emer == 0) 0.1913 0.0785  0.36
```

I get that this is a point estimate of 19.1% with a CI of [7.9%, 36.0%]. But 19% is a proportion of *what*? Teachers with emergency credentials as a proportion of *all* teachers in a school? A school district? But it can't be teachers with emergency credentials because a value of "0" in "emer" already means that 0% of the teachers have emergency credentials, right?

I'd be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this.

Thanks,
David

Comment: you dont need `I` in this situation, but the `I` function allows you to perform arithmetic within a formula where some operators have special meaning, for example `y ~ a + b` and `y ~ I(a + b)`. `I(emer==0)` or simply `emer==0` _does_ create a binary variable. your question about model interpretation is better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, @rawr! I'm wondering if you could elucidate on how ```(emer==0)``` creates a binary variable. What are the values of the binary variable created, how do they map onto the existing values of "emer", and what's the name of the new variable? As for model "interpretation," it's not really a question of statistical interpretation, but a question about the ```survey``` package and the ```api``` datasets.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. ```emer==0``` creates a logical value of "TRUE" when "emer" = 0 and "FALSE" otherwise. The proportion estimated by ```svyciprop```, .193, is simply the percentage of all "emer" observations that have a value of 0, as can be seen by:  ```svyciprop(~I(emer==0), rclus1, method="me")``` and ```sum(apiclus1$emer==0)/length(apiclus1$emer)```